# How to get force feedback on Logitech Momo Racing

Tags: joystick

I have an old Logitech Momo Racing wheel. My Ubuntu 20.04 desktop does detect the weel and all buttons/axis are working but not the force feedback.
Is there any possibility to enable this?

Here is the output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:ca03 Logitech, Inc. MOMO Racing
```

When trying to test the force feedback with `fftest` I have the following output

```
Force feedback test program.
HOLD FIRMLY YOUR WHEEL OR JOYSTICK TO PREVENT DAMAGES

Device /dev/input/event0 opened
Features:
  * Absolute axes: 
    [00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]
  * Relative axes: 
    [00 00 ]
  * Force feedback effects types: 
    Force feedback periodic effects: 
    [00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]
  * Number of simultaneous effects: 0

Uploading effect #0 (Periodic sinusoidal) ... Error:: Function not implemented
Uploading effect #1 (Constant) ... Error: Function not implemented
Uploading effect #2 (Spring) ... Error: Function not implemented
Uploading effect #3 (Damper) ... Error: Function not implemented
Uploading effect #4 (Strong rumble, with heavy motor) ... Error: Function not implemented
Uploading effect #5 (Weak rumble, with light motor) ... Error: Function not implemented
```

I have installed `ltwheelconf` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/474103/24931) but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: "Function not implemented" probably means just that, not supported by the driver.

Comment: Indeed, maybe I should rephrase my question: "Is there a driver available to enable force feedback for Logitech Momo Racing"?